# User Group or Role based on logged in user at Client side script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How to get the user groups or roles for the current logged in user? I need to find this from the javascript/jquery. Is it possible ? I may get the current logged in user id from _spPageContextInfo.userId. Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somone has already done most if not all the work for you ;) , its using the javascript client object model so you can utilise the sharepoint library.

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(strGroupName, functionComplete) {

        //Setup Vars
        currentContext  = null;
        currentWeb  = null;
        allGroups   = null;
        leaderGroup     = null;
        currentUser     = null;
        groupUsers  = null;

        //Get an instance of the Client Content.
        currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

        //Grab the client web object.
        currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

        //Get the current user object
        currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        currentContext.load(currentUser);

        //Setup the groupColletion.
        allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        currentContext.load(allGroups);

        //Now populate the objects above.
        currentContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, GetAllGroupsExecuteOnSuccess),
            Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure)
        );

        // GroupCollection - Load - SUCCESS
        function GetAllGroupsExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {

            // CHECK THE GROUPS
            // Time to Enumerate through the group collection that was returned.
            var groupEnumerator = allGroups.getEnumerator();

            // Loop for the collection.
            while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                //Grab the Group Item.
                var group = groupEnumerator.get_current();
                if (group.get_title().indexOf(strGroupName) > -1) {

                    // Now that we have the group let's grab the list of users.
                    groupUsers = group.get_users();
                    currentContext.load(groupUsers);
                    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(
                        Function.createDelegate(this, SingleGroupExecuteOnSuccess),
                        Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure)
                    );
                }
            }
        }

        // Single Group - Load - SUCCESS
        function SingleGroupExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) {

            // Time to setup the Enumerator
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();

            // This is the flag to set to true if the user is in the group.
            var boolUserInGroup = false;

            // and start looping.
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {

                //Grab the User Item.
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();

                // and finally. If a Group User ID Matches the current user ID then they are in the group!
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    boolUserInGroup = true;
                }
            }

            //Run the delegate function with the bool;
            functionComplete(boolUserInGroup);
        }

        // GroupCollection or Single Group - Load - FAILURE
        function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) {
            //Run the delegate function and return false because there was no match.
            functionComplete(false);
        }
 }
```

http://styledpoint.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-check-to-see-if-user-exists-in-a-group-via-javascript-ecma/

looks like you need to get the object more than once!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want the all the  role Id's or group names assigned for the current user. How can I get that using this ?

Comment: just ammended answer

Comment: I'm not getting the getEnumerator method for groups. Getting error!   ""groups.getEnumerator(); The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested. Error""

Comment: just ammended the answer

Comment: groupUsers.get_count() is throwing error!! "  groupUsers.get_count() "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.""

Comment: iv just ammended the answer! it was getting the error because it wasnt loading the object in the first place! i presume you just copied pasted in? if you follow it back to this line ContextUserGroup.get_web().get_siteGroups(); i had a space between the . that caused an error! iv corrected it and it should work properly this time,,, same example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185012(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Eventhough I have copied the code, I have corrected this before. But, my error is still there! :( groupUsers object is available, but still it throws the same error as above.. It happens only for some values!!

Comment: Is it something to do with executeQueryAsync ?

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: Getting an error.. "ContextUserGroup.executeQuery(); Object doesn't support property or method 'executeQuery' Error"

Comment: How to add call executeQueryAsync in a loop? I want to make sure that it gets executed before the loop continues with new value.

Comment: just ammended the answer! rather than trying to make another call to get the group users, I did first before calling the execute and putting it in a varible so you could use it in the method

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error, when I try to save it to a variable! Collection not initialized!! Do we need to add it to the context before taking the count() ?

Comment: yes you do, thats what its complaining about!

Comment: context.load(group);
             context.load(groupUsers);
             var groupUserCount = groupUsers.get_count();
             context.load(groupUserCount); This is my code block.. Still the same error!

Comment: just ammended my answer! iv ammended the code! this is one version and should work properly.... i dont really have the time to go through the other code but it has todo with loading the users into the group or user object and then iterating throug it..clientContext.Load(collGroup,
                groups => groups.Include(
                    group => group.Users));
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538244(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2):

At least two options are available to find a groups of which the specified user is a member

### How to retrieve groups of which the specified user is a member via CSOM

The specified function returns the collection of groups of which the specified user is a member:

```
function GetGroupCollectionFromCurrentUser(OnSuccess,OnError) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    var groups = currentUser.get_groups();

    context.load(groups);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      OnSuccess(groups)
    },
    OnError);        
}
```

Example:

```
//Print groups for a current user
GetGroupCollectionFromCurrentUser(function(groups){
    var e = groups.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
       var group = e.get_current();
       console.log(group.get_title());               
    }
  },
  function(sender,args){
    console.log('An error occured:' + args.get_message());
  }
);
```

---

### How to retrieve groups of which the specified user is a member via [UserGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772575%28v=office.12%29.aspx) SOAP service

[UserGroup.GetGroupCollectionFromUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772552%28v=office.12%29.aspx)  Returns information about the collection of groups of which the specified user is a member

Example (SPServices is used here):

```
function getGroupsForCurrentUser()
{
  $().SPServices({
      operation: "GetGroupCollectionFromUser",
      userLoginName: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({ webURL: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl }),
      async: false,
      completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        //Process xData.responseXML goes here...
      }
  });
```

Please follow [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetGroupCollectionFromUser) documentation for a more details

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I'm trying the first method. But, I'm not getting any groups!! Hence, I have checked the currentUser. Its also showing one error message if I try to get the currentUser.get_loginName(). The error message is as follows: The property or field 'LoginName' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: "var groups = currentUser.get_groups(); " is not working for me. Its seems an object is returning, but its not entering in the while loop.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify how the function GetGroupCollectionFromCurrentUser is called in your case?