# JS failures using ClientContext object on pages other than group membership pages

Tags: 2013, user-profile, core-api

I'm attempting to use a piece of JS that I located [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89241/user-group-or-role-based-on-logged-in-user-at-client-side-script) to add some CCS classes to the body tag of my SP site based on the user's groups. The following script works perfectly well when looking at a particular group's membership page. (`sites/[mysite]/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=XXX`)

But, the script throws a `Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined` error anywhere else.

The relevant code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// generic function to grab user groups from collection. Used to append class names to body tag for CSS styling.
// Inspired by: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89241/user-group-or-role-based-on-logged-in-user-at-client-side-script

function GetGroupCollectionFromCurrentUser(OnSuccess,OnError) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    var groups = currentUser.get_groups();

    context.load(groups);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      OnSuccess(groups)
    },
    OnError);        
}

GetGroupCollectionFromCurrentUser(function(groups){
    var e = groups.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
       var group = e.get_current();
       var groupClass = (group.get_title()).replace(/\s+/g, '');
       $("body").addClass("group-" + groupClass);              
    }
  },
  function(sender,args){
    console.log('An error occured:' + args.get_message());
  }
);

.... more code, all working.

});
```

When not producing an error, the body class of the page looks like:

```
<body ... class="group-groupName group-SecondGroupName" ... >
```

**My question:** Is there a better way to call these functions so that I can acheive the desired result? Is there better way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error:

> Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined

usually occurs since `sp.js` library is *not yet loaded* when the `ClientContext` is initialized.  Use `SP.SOD.executeFunc` function to ensure `sp.js` is loaded.

**Example**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { 

    getGroupsFromCurrentUser(function(groups){
       groups.forEach(function(g){
          console.log(g.get_title());               
       });
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log('An error occured:' + args.get_message());
    });


});


function getGroupsFromCurrentUser(success,error) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
    var groups = currentUser.get_groups();
    context.load(groups);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
      success(groups.get_data());
    },
    error);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadim-gremyachev. Worked well!  I placed both of these functions outside of the context of the document ready call, and added back the `.addClass` function where it should go and it now works across all pages. Cheers!